# Hashicorp Vault Server UI loads a blank screen

Tags: windows, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am trying to run hashicorp vault server as windows service in windows 10 system.
Vault server UI is showing as blank screen.
Please refer my configuration details.

**config.hcl**

```
ui = true

backend "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  path = "vault/"
}

listener "tcp" {
 address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
 tls_disable = 1
 tls_cert_file = "c:/vault/config/certificate.crt"
 tls_key_file  = "c:/vault/config/privkey.key"
}
```

By default vault server is running in this (http://localhost:8200/ui/) local URL.  When i navigate to this 8200 port , Blank ui screen is displayed.

[Console log of Vault UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VNLb.png)

But at the same time hashicorp vault server UI is loading if we run vault as container based application.

**Windows service command I used to run vault service:**

```
sc.exe create VaultAgent binPath= "C:\vault\vault.exe server -config=C:\vault\config\config.hcl" displayName= "Vault Agent" start= auto
```

Note: vault.exe is downloaded from [vault windows amd64 version](https://www.vaultproject.io/downloads) this url.

I am able to receive the response from vault server. Please refer the image.
[vault server backend response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkvG6.png)

**Note:** Consul service is up and running. Please refer the image.
[consul server up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQuQ3.png)

How to bring up the Vault server UI up and running? Am i missing something.?

Note: Below are the Vault server UI console logs

```
unseal:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:8200/ui/assets/vendor-dd308e6ebdb070a5a829a0c0d6e74f61.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

unseal:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:8200/ui/assets/vault-8a8f62829e5ad33487e21f63af47c80d.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

unseal:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:8200/ui/sw-registration-1b862bc1e33e4a8a41781d56c3469209.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I came across with this problem and can't find a solution

Comment: @NihatMert No, I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: The root cause might be a bug in Vault, coupled with your browser enforcing strict MIME type checking. I bet that log is not coming from Vault, but from your browser. Try Firefox (if you are on Chrome/Opera/Edge) or vice-versa.

Comment: Let me confirm you by trying in Firefox. But same vault service is running when I make it as containerisation (docker). Same browser but no issues.

Comment: In firefox also kind of same issue. Please refer the logs => 
The resource from “http://localhost:8200/ui/assets/vault-8a8f62829e5ad33487e21f63af47c80d.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

None of the “sha512” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource. ui
The resource from “http://localhost:8200/ui/assets/vendor-dd308e6ebdb070a5a829a0c0d6e74f61.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: @NihatMert As mentioned in below link,  we are able to run the vault successfully. But this is not working with latest version of vault.
Source url: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/13357

Download url: https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.8.8/vault_1.8.8_windows_amd64.zip

Comment: Well, I tried several versions (1.10.1, 1.9.5, 1.9.4) and still had the same problem.  I jumped back to 1.6.7 and it worked out of the box (on PC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of the Hashicorp is having an bug and it is in opened stage. Please refer the url.
[GitHub issue link](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/13357)

So you can little go back with old version(1.8.8) of vault and try to run it as windows service and UI should be up and running.

Note: v 1.8.8 is having it's own feature and not having all the features of the latest vault version.

[Download the 1.8.8 vault for windows](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.8.8/vault_1.8.8_windows_amd64.zip)

Comment: Thank you! Downgrading to v1.8.8 from v1.10.0 worked.